# Coldfusion Lots of loops vs query of queries

Tags: loops, coldfusion, row, coldfusion-8

I am deleting login records in my database that don't have a corresponding logout record, but right now it's very slow It does this:

First it gets the queries to loop over to check to delete
Next it needs to find out if the next record for that user is a login or logout, if it's a login, I delete it.

To get the next record of that type it does this query of query:

```
<cfquery dbtype="query" name="getnext" maxrows="1">
SELECT * FROM getlogs WHERE id > #id# AND logType = 'login'
</cfquery>
```

But it's slow, doing it thousands of times makes it take about 56 seconds.

What would be a faster way to do this? Would another cfloop inside my loop (basicly a loop until I get to the row I want) be faster? Is there another way?

Comment: Instead of having one query to get all the logs, then another query to delete each individual record (I assume that's what you're doing, or do you just create a list of records and then delete them all in one query?), can't you just do it all in one query?

Comment: I'm doing it all in one query already.

Comment: no, you're doing 1 query to get the records, then thousands of query-of-queries, then one query to delete some records, right?  So why not just do it all in only 1 query, no query-of-queries.  Just do a nested select, it should be possible.

Comment: What do you mean nested select?

Comment: DELETE
FROM yourTable
WHERE ID IN (
 SELECT ID
 FROM yourTable
 WHERE (some criteria)
)

Comment: Yes, but, the way I'm deleting things is complacated, I'm deleting records that don't have a logout record after them, can I do this without ColdFusion? It's the criteria that I don't know how to do. Also

Comment: It might be useful to show us more of your SQL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like something that can be done entirely in one query -- perhaps something like this:

```
delete from login_table t
where exists (
  select id
  from   login_table
  where  id > t.id
  and    logtype = 'login'
)
```

This has nothing to do with ColdFusion per se; the same approach would apply in any environment. If this is a maintenance function that has no synchronous dependence on your application, you could even stick it into a stored procedure invoked automatically by a recurring "cleanup" task in the database itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to do it all in sql, using cursors or a temp table. That saves the roundtrips between the CF and sql servers.